# Mysql Query to Select data where, WHERE clause contains both comma separated and individual values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql field which may contain single **center_id** values like **AB** or csv values like **AB,AJ** etc..

Currently i do the following in php:

```
$usercenter = $_SESSION['usercenter'];
$searchForValue = ',';
if( strpos($usercenter, $searchForValue) !== false ) {
$centerid = explode(',', $usercenter);
}
else  {
$centerid = $usercenter;    
}
```

and in sql query i do:

```
SELECT id,node
FROM followup
WHERE center_id IN('".implode("','",$centerid)."')
```

If there are csv values, it works correctly. How can I write the query to check for both **csv values** and **single** value ??

Requesting help..

Comment: The real fix here is probably to normalize the data so one column doesn't contain multiple values, so you don't have to do tricks with querying the data.  Is that an option in your case?

Comment: It is passed from a multiselect field. Hence stored as csv values in the field.

Comment: The multiselect could be either 1 value or more values..

Comment: Then it sounds like the answer is yes, this is an option here.  You should create a second table for storing the related values.  Something like a `followup_center` table.  Each record in that new table would contain a foreign key to `followup` and a Center ID value.  So it could hold zero-to-many values for each `followup` record.  Then in your `SELECT` you would join the two tables and query on the exact values, rather than doing string manipulation like this.

Comment: How can you tell the difference between a single value versus a comma-separated list with one element?

Answer (score 1):

Given your schema the only solution I can think of is using `LIKE`.

`SELECT id, node FROM followup WHERE center_id LIKE "%AD%"`;

But this will also select rows with `CAD`, `ADA` etc. and can only used to check a single option per condition (so you would have to use `AND`/`OR` with multiple `LIKE` statements.)

Also your solution is kind of an antipattern. Normally you would use a one-to-many relation for this.

Comment: I just provided an example, like AB,AJ etc..It could be anything and multiple or single values

Comment: It's kind of a hack, but if one always adds the commas before and after the stored value (so e.g. `",AB,AJ,"` in the data) then the `LIKE` could do the same: `... LIKE '%,AJ,%'`  This should prevent the false positives.  But you're right, normalizing the data is the real solution here.  I just don't think we know enough about the system to provide a complete solution in that regard, as much of the application logic would have to change as well.

Comment: Any time I've had to use a solution like this for a comma separated list in a DB, I always loop through the data before using it and `explode()` that column by the comma to make sure my value is actually there.

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't use indexed values (so for huge datasets it can be rather slow), you can use the MySQL function `FIND_IN_SET()`. This can search for a single value in a comma-separated list.

While this can't search for multiple values at once, from what I understand in the question, you're just looking for a single value at a time.

The function takes the value to search for (case-sensitive!), and then the column to search in.

```
SELECT id,node
FROM followup
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('AB', center_id)
```

- [DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pEQiGZPbomon2g8VHEMmc1/0)

If its the other way around, and you're looking to use all those values in a `WHERE IN (..)`, then you can just `explode()` it regardless if it is one or not - the returnvalue will be an array which you can use, it doesn't matter if its 1 or greater length. You should however, use a prepared statement in doing so. You can achieve that by generating a dynamic query based on the length of the array.

MySQLi:

```php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); // Set MySQLi to throw exceptions - this allows you to automagically check for errors 

// Create connection, $mysqli = new mysqli(...);

$parts = explode(',', $usercenter); // Split the comma-separated values 
if (empty($parts)) {
    // Handle it
}

// Generate dynamic SQL, execute and fetch
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, node
                          FROM followup 
                          WHERE center_id IN (".implode(',', array_fill(0, count($parts ), '?')).")");
$stmt->bind_param(str_repeat("s", count($parts)), ...$parts);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $node);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    // Use $id and $node for each row
}
$stmt->close();
```

PDO:

```php
// Create connection, $pdo = new PDO(...);
// You should set PDO to throw exceptions on errors

$parts = explode(',', $usercenter); // Split the comma-separated values 
if (empty($parts)) {
    // Handle it
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, node
                          FROM followup 
                          WHERE center_id IN (".implode(',', array_fill(0, count($parts ), '?')).")");
$stmt->execute([...$parts]);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // Use $row['id'] and $row['node'] for each row
}
```

You might also want to look into filtering out empty values after exploding.

Comment: sorry, that is not my requirement.

Comment: WHERE center_id IN

Comment: @Pamela Is the updated answer more what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You should use FIND_IN_SET() function returns the position of a string within a list of strings. it is working both comma separated and individual values. try the following query

```
SELECT id,node
FROM followup
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('center_id','".implode("','",$centerid)."')
```